# How can I convert a jar file into apk format?

Tags: java, android, jar, apk

I need to find a way to convert jar file to apk file. I have reached a road block!

Comment: converting a jar into apk could be a good idea as it came to my mind too. But you would have to compromise with graphics in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Is the JAR natively made for Android? If not, you'll have to run it in an emulation layer or something like this: http://microemu.blogspot.com/2008/11/running-java-me-applications-on-android.html

Good luck?

Answer (score 3):

I've never tried this tool, but you can give it a go:

http://www.netmite.com/android/srv/1.7/getapk.php

If it doesn't work then I think you'll have to use an emulator on the device, or create an apk from source, as expressed by Blender and burpen.

Comment: It needs the J2ME_Runner emulator which can be downloaded at the same site. I would select this as the answer to the above question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=456634) on xda-devs, you might be able to use something like [this](http://microemu.blogspot.com/2008/11/running-java-me-applications-on-android.html). However, if you have the source for the jar, then you might as well compile the apk from the source. It seems to depend on what the jar was compiled as.

Answer (score 0):

ok, guess the only way around it is to run the application on an android emulator, when that is done, an apk file is automatically generated in the project directory. If the application is not built by using android libraries then the only way to get an apk file is to rewrite the code by using android libraries and run it on an emulator. Bad news for me and some of you.