# How to create .apk file using maven build, I have dynamic web project

Tags: maven, web, build, apk, project

I have dynamic web project in eclipse.
We create WAR file of it to use it as web application using maven build.

We want to deploy same project on android , how can we do it using maven build?

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346924/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-file-into-apk-format

Comment: thanks akhilsk, As per above link we need to have emulator to create .apk file. is there any other way using only maven build and some plugins with it ?